# Hibernate showing error when trying to run app IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, hibernate

When I'm trying to put some data to database via hibernate i'm getting this error pointing on session.save(userLoginAndPassword);

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.packagename.myapp.spring.HibernateFiles.UserLoginAndPassword.login
at com.packagename.myapp.spring.HibernateFiles.HibernateConnect.setAll(HibernateConnect.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename.myapp.spring.HibernateFiles.HibernateConnect.saveLoginAndPassword(HibernateConnect.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
at com.packagename.myapp.spring.ViewClasses.RegisterView.lambda$new$9b1b5227$1(RegisterView.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
```

I was trying to make it the same way like in my previous project but it doesn't work.

There is code of my app:

```
package com.packagename.myapp.spring.HibernateFiles;

public class UserLoginAndPassword {

    private int id;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Name of this file: UserLoginAndPassword.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>


<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.packagename.myapp.spring.HibernateFiles.UserLoginAndPassword" table="UserLoginAndPassword">

        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="IDUser"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name="login" type="string">
            <column name="Login"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="Password"/>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
package com.packagename.myapp.spring.HibernateFiles;


import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;


public class HibernateConnect {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static void setUp(){
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure()
                .build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy( registry );
        }
    }

    public static void setAll(String login, String haslo){
        UserLoginAndPassword userLoginAndPassword = new UserLoginAndPassword();

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        userLoginAndPassword.setLogin(login);
        userLoginAndPassword.setPassword(haslo);
        session.save(userLoginAndPassword);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }

    private static boolean checkIfLoginExist(String login){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.createQuery("from UserLoginAndPassword where UserLoginAndPassword.login = ?")
                    .addQueryHint(login)
                    .uniqueResult();
            session.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            session.close();
            return false;
        }


    }



    public static boolean saveLoginAndPassword(String login, String password, String passwordCheck){
        if(login.length() >= 6 && login.length() <= 24 && password.length() >= 6 && password.length() <= 24 && password.equals(passwordCheck)) {
            if(checkIfLoginExist(login)){
                Notification notification = new Notification("Login jest już zajęty", 5000, Notification.Position.TOP_CENTER);
                notification.open();
            }
            else{
                setAll(login, password);
                Notification notification = new Notification("Login nie jest zajęty", 5000, Notification.Position.TOP_CENTER);
                notification.open();
            }
        }
        else{
            Notification notification = new Notification("Sprawdź czy hasło i login mają od 6 do 24 znaków!", 5000, Notification.Position.TOP_CENTER);
            notification.open();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>



        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nowadlahibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.username">krystian</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1234</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="UserLoginAndPassword.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-confi
```

Comment: if you remove type to propriety tag?

Comment: You mean to remove type from .hbm.xml file in id?

Comment: No I mean you should remove the string type because it should a primary type

Comment: It should look like this? <id name="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name="login">
        </property>
        <property name="password">
        </property> It's still don't working

Comment: Yes if you try to remove type="string" should be work, right?

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Same exception?

Comment: can you control your package type? an example, the String to de package "java.lang", because this error should be caused to reflection because hibernate not found the get and set fo the type inside the package

Comment: Yes, everything same. Here I have link to github https://github.com/433MHz/Hibernate-web-login-and-register

Comment: You mean to do something like this? <property name="login" type="java.lang.String"/> It's also don't working, same result

Comment: try to delete `<property name="login"/>` and `<property name="password"/>`